# Make new multi line string variable in jinja template with other variables

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have some lenghty property tags I need to repeat on several attributes. For this example, let's assume it are some `data-attributes`, so

```
<tag1 data-attr1="{{value1}}" data-attr2="{{value2}}" ... data-attrN="{{valueN}}">
<tag2 data-attr1="{{value1}}" data-attr2="{{value2}}" ... data-attrN="{{valueN}}">
<tagX data-attr1="{{value1}}" data-attr2="{{value2}}" ... data-attrN="{{valueN}}">
```

I would like to rewrite this to not repeat the same string over and over. I'm trying the syntax below, but it results in an empty string.

```
{% set data_attributes = '
 data-attr1="{{value1}}" data-attr2="{{value2}}" 
 ... data-attrN="{{valueN}}"'%}
<tag1 {{data_attributes}}>
<tag2 {{data_attributes}}>
<tagX {{data_attributes}}>
```

Resulting HTML

```
 <tag 1 >
 <tag 2 >
 <tag 3 >
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure value1 has any value? What if you just put on your page something like {{value1}} - will it show anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a long string and wanted to wrap it as well. This worked for me without issue.

```
{% set error_message = 'Really long string that I wanted to wrap to 
                        multiple lines to help meet pep8 column width
                        error checking.' %}
<p><strong>
  {{ error_message }}
</strong></p>
```

## In your case though, I would probably do this instead.

```
  <div data-attr1="{{ variable_here }}"
       data-attr2="apples"
       data-attr3="oranges">
    Stuff
  </div>
```

The rendered HTML would be:

```
<div data-attr1="bananas" data-attr2="apples" data-attr3="oranges">
    Stuff
</div>
```

Comment: I think the point this answer was missing is that it is annoying to write all the `data-attr` on each of the `div` that needs them. I think I went for some more complicated jquery asking them from the parent.